# How to avoid unnecessary recomputation in sklearn GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to apply grid search to identify the numbers of features that should be selected:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

data = load_breast_cancer()

parameters = {'select__k': range(1,11)}

p = Pipeline([('select', SelectKBest(chi2)), ('model', LogisticRegression())])
clf = GridSearchCV(p, parameters, cv=10, refit=False)
clf.fit(data.data, data.target)
```

So, for each fold, it will calculate a ranking. However, instead of calculating this ranking only once, sklearn calculates it **number_of_folds * number_of_parameters** times. In this case, 100 times instead of just 10 times. Is there a way to give sklearn a hint to avoid recomputation?

**Update:**

I found a solution but it is pretty hacky. So, if you have any better idea, let me know:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

map_fold2ranking = {}

class WrapperSelection(SelectKBest):
    def __init__(self, selection, k=10):
        self.k = k
        self.selection = selection

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        hash_for_fold_ids = np.sum(X.index.values)

        if hash_for_fold_ids in map_fold2ranking:
            self.scores_ = map_fold2ranking[hash_for_fold_ids]
            return self
        self.selection.fit(X,y)
        map_fold2ranking[hash_for_fold_ids] = self.selection.scores_
        self.scores_ = self.selection.scores_

        return self

data = load_breast_cancer()

parameters = {'select__k': range(1, 11)}

p = Pipeline([('select', WrapperSelection(SelectKBest(chi2))), ('model', LogisticRegression())])
clf = GridSearchCV(p, parameters, cv=10, refit=False)
clf.fit(pd.DataFrame(data.data), data.target)
```

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

> However, instead of calculating this ranking only once, sklearn calculates it number_of_folds * number_of_parameters times.

This is exactly the purpose of [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). The model is evaluated over all the partitions of the data and for all the parameters over each partition.

From the docs:

> Exhaustive search over specified parameter values for an estimator.

Comment: So, you do not agree that we could save computation in this case?

Comment: The computations are not repetitive. They are done over different partitions of the data. If you want to save some compute time you can look for randomsearch sklearn. It performs at par with grid search and generally iterates over less number of parameters.

Comment: The computation is repetitive. It would be enough to calculate the ranking for each fold once. This means we need to calculate the ranking ten times for ten-fold cross-validation. Afterward, we can apply different ks to these rankings.